# .NET 6 - Этот сайт вызова доступен на всех платформах. "IdentityNotMappedException" поддерживается только в 'windows'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, roslyn-code-analysis

Совершенно не понятно, по какой причине появляется этот ворнинг (как в заголовке, дословно) и что он значит. Сама формулировка, как мне кажется, содержит в себе противоречие. Дока [говорит](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.identitynotmappedexception.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-security-principal-identitynotmappedexception-ctor(system-string)), что класс доступен на всех платформах. Кто может прояснить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD
Нашёл доку по этому правилу - [CA1416: Validate platform compatibility](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416), но всё равно не особо понятно.

Comment: Метки слишком редкие, поэтому вопрос остался незамеченным. Добавил более общие метки для привлечения внимания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предупреждение достаточно однозначно - этот код доступен только на Windows. С выходом .NET 6, они начали помечать часть кода специальными атрибутами (или указывать в настройках проекта), что этот код доступен только на определенной платформе. Я чаще такие пометки встречал для `Blazor`.

Увидеть это можно посмотрев в исходный код .NET: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.Security.Principal.Windows.

Directory.Build.props

```xml
<Project>
  <Import Project="..\Directory.Build.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StrongNameKeyId>Microsoft</StrongNameKeyId>
    <SupportedOSPlatforms>windows</SupportedOSPlatforms>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

что собственно и указывает на Windows. И если вы запустите такой код не на `Windows`, то получите исключение:

> Unhandled exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Windows Principal functionality is not supported on this platform.

Т.к. `.NET 6` кросплатформенный и даже если вы это собираете и запускаете на `Windows` это не означает, что этот же код будет/должен работать на других платформах.

Поэтому если вы предполагаете, что ваш код будет работать только на Windows, то вы можете указать это в настройках проекта и предупреждения исчезнут:

```xml
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: этот код работает не на винде без каких либо проблем. или вы имеете в виду, что ошибка будет при попытке выбросить такое исключение?

Comment: и что тогда означает фраза *Этот сайт вызова доступен на всех платформах*?

Comment: @Anatol - по-английски там "This call site is reachable on all platforms". Перевод на русский сделан коряво. Вот что удалось найти: [Call site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_site). Правильнее перевести как "место вызова".

Comment: Правильнее, наверно, было бы так: "Вызов этого метода/конструктора доступен на всех платформах. Но поддерживается только на Windows".

Comment: @Anatol, ну например у меня на Mac, если просто попытаться создать (через new, но без throw) `IdentityNotMappedException`, то будет выброшено исключение `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

Comment: Такие вещи собираются позже портировать или вообще исключать из сдк, есть у вас понимание? Как по мне - дизайн странноватый для кроссплатформенного фреймворка